# How can I customized the date format displaying of UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

The question is I wanna customized the date format displaying of the UIDatePicker in iOS system.Because the system just provides four modes to display as the following:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDatePickerMode) {

    UIDatePickerModeTime,           // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)

    UIDatePickerModeDate,           // Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)

    UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,    // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)

    UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer, // Displays hour and minute (e.g. 1 | 53)

} __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

the system's UI effect :

[image]

I wanna customized the format displaying, the picture as the following:
[image]

Can anyone give me a favor?Or give me some ideas.thanks a lot.

Comment: you cannot customize the defalut picker date instead you need to create UIpickerview with the details mentioned above

Comment: I believe that you are only looking for changing the format of UIDatePicker, but not the language displayed. The format is not possible to change. But, the language can be. Let me know

Comment: @KrishnaCA Yep,I just wanna change the format of UIDatePicker,such as 'month - day - time'.It's easy to change the language.you just need to change the locale the property of UIDatePicker.

Comment: @Vinodh It seems that the only way to solve this problem is creating a UIPickerView binding the date's data source.Thanks your advice

Comment: @JimmyNgYou cannot able to set date format of UIDatePicker programatically. The date format based on region set on the device and it's local date format. You need to create custom date picker using UIPickerView.